# knockout foreach with alternating classes

Tags: knockout.js

Could someone more knowledgeable in knockout tell me if I'm doing this the correct way?

I am trying to add float left and float right class alternately in a foreach directive - here is my binding.
Am I way off mark? Is there a better approach?

```
<a data-bind="css:{'pull-left':$index()%2 == 0,'pull-right':$index()%2 == 1}, attr:{href:$data.url}">
```

Loving knockout - btw

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that you are doing it will work.  If you want a cleaner way to do it, then you could either create a computed observable on your view model that returns the right values or even better a custom binding that handles this logic for you.

A sample of a custom binding where you can pass what you want to use as the index might look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.float = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var index, floatValue;

        index = valueAccessor();

        floatValue = ko.computed(function() {
           var left = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(index) % 2 === 0; 
           return left ? "left" : "right";
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { 
            style: {
                cssFloat: floatValue
            }                
        });
    }        
};
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/B8YHc/

If you want to use bootstrap's classes, then you could do it like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/VdLNQ/.  They just do float left/right, so either way should be fine.

Comment: Thanks RP, I think I'll create a custom binding - cleans it up nicely.

Comment: Not all browsers will allow `float` to be unquoted as an object property name. Also not all browsers support using `float` as a style from Javascript. The standard method is to use `cssFloat`.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer. I guess I have always used classes rather than set the style directly.